# Break up first and last names in Excel when dealing with addresses with two person households

Tags: microsoft-excel

I received a request at work that I am having a tough time fulfilling but anyone who really knows Excel should be good at.

Details

- Received massive data set of names and addresses.
- Order is to break up first and last names into two separate columns
- Tricky part is two-person households.
- For data privacy concerns, I created a fake data set that shows you what I'm looking at and what I need.
- I think it will end up being a very complex "IF" function but I do not know how to approach it.
- Keep in mind, the address must be duplicated after splitting the households.

[image]

Comment: How should the two-person households look?

Comment: @ScottCraner Look at the screenshot at the bottom where it says “What I need it to look like.” Also, to the original poster, do not ever demand “immediate assistance” as you did with [your original post](https://superuser.com/revisions/1430127/1). Everyone here is volunteering their time and people can answer questions if you give them time and real details; demanding “immediate” help only results in people not taking you seriously.

Comment: I tried showing in the picture, the last name needs to be duplicated as does the address and the "&" deleted. For example, look at Emily and John Leach in pic

Comment: EDIT: I messed up the second table with Paolo and Shrey, the last name should have been deleted in column A. Everything below that is what it should look like

Comment: You will want vba.  Formulas will not work well here.

Comment: And what about two part last names ie `Ian Van Strucker` How is Excel to know what to do with the `Van`

Comment: @ScottCraner If you spit names based on two items, with a space as a delimiter, then you can get “Ian” and then “Van Strucker.” But I do not know enough about Excel or VBA to know how to handle that. Most programming language can handle that.

Comment: @JakeGould that's what I did to split first names, I had been hoping a complex "If" function could find the "&" and work from there but that might be unrealistic

Comment: @JakeGould I just read your first message, I apologize if my title was rude, I meant to emphasize time-sensitivity, but I see I did it poorly

Comment: Okay you can split on the first space easily enough in vba, but what about two word first names? `Lee Anne Smith`  Names are hard in that it is arbitrary where the first name and the last name are.  It is not always two words, one each.  Sometimes it is two word fist names and sometimes it is two word second names.  Unless you can guarantee the data coming in is always one format there will be errors in the conversions.

Comment: This is a hard subject for even the most complex programs written to do this very job.  Other tough examples:  Mr. & Mrs. John K. Stevens, John Smith & Tonya Tucker,The Smith Family etc...  Then there are other nationalities with surnames first or special characters.  Complex duplicate detection software is the best to attack this and 'data salvage' the records by splitting them.  Even after that I do final cleaning by hand with database software to attain the fewest errors.

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/)

Comment: Just to add to the variables, is only `&` used, or could it be `and`?

Answer (score 0):

If your data is truly representative, in that there is only a single `Last Name`, then it is simple to do this in `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform` which has been part of Excel (either as a MS supplied add-in; or built-in) since 2010.

If you have instances of multiple-word last names, you will have to either handle this manually, or use a different algorithm

The commands from the UI:

- Split column by delimiter; space; rightmost

[image]

- Split column by delimiter; ampersand; advanced options: into Rows

[image]

- Rename the first and second columns `First Name`, `Last Name`
- Close and Load

[image]